# Formatting memory size values

Tags: java, android

### to get memory details of phone

```
    //total
       StatFs statF = new StatFs(Environment.getDataDirectory().getAbsolutePath());

        float total = ((float)statF.getBlockCount() * statF.getBlockSize()) / 1073741824;
        TextView tt = (TextView) ax.findViewById(R.id.total1);
        tt.setText(String.valueOf(total)+"GB");

    //free
     StatFs statFs = new StatFs(Environment.getDataDirectory().getAbsolutePath());

       float free  = ((float)statFs.getAvailableBlocks() * statFs.getBlockSize()) / 1073741824;
           TextView t = (TextView) ax.findViewById(R.id.free1);
           t.setText(String.valueOf(free)+"GB");
    //use
           float use = total - free ;
       TextView ttt = (TextView) ax.findViewById(R.id.use1);
           ttt.setText(String.valueOf(use)+"GB");
```

i am using this  code but i am getting output in  11.350227GB 
 i want it shld display 11.35 gb and when it goes below 1 gb then it shld display MB(ie 800mb etc..) so how i can get it

Answer (score 0):

There is no direct way to do this but you can have the following solution

```
private static final long K = 1024;
private static final long M = K * K;
private static final long G = M * K;
private static final long T = G * K;

public static String convertToStringRepresentation(final long value){
    final long[] dividers = new long[] { T, G, M, K, 1 };
    final String[] units = new String[] { "TB", "GB", "MB", "KB", "B" };
    if(value < 1)
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("Invalid file size: " + value);
    String result = null;
    for(int i = 0; i < dividers.length; i++){
        final long divider = dividers[i];
        if(value >= divider){
            result = format(value, divider, units[i]);
            break;
        }
     }
    return result;
}

private static String format(final long value,
    final long divider,
    final String unit){
    final double result =
        divider > 1 ? (double) value / (double) divider : (double) value;
    return new DecimalFormat("#,##0.#").format(result) + " " + unit;
}
```

Comment: can u tell me hw i can use in given progrm? i spend almot 1 day i am nt getting it

Comment: send the total which you are calculating to the format function above.

Comment: I am using this in public class memory implement fragment {} no function

Answer (score 0):

Use [android.text.format.Formatter.formatFileSize()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/format/Formatter.html#formatFileSize%28android.content.Context,%20long%29).